# How to test if exception was caught while running a django test

Tags: django, exception, python-3.7, django-tests

Suppose this is my code:

```
def fun():
   try:
      raise Exception("An exception")
   except Exception as e:
      logger.debug(f'{e}')
```

Now how can I write a test case which checks if that particular exception was caught?
I could have tested by reading `sys.stderr`, but I'm using `logger.debug`.
I'm using django `TestCase`

Comment: Please share your test class, are you using pytest?

Comment: Django TestCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [assertLogs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertLogs), but i suggest to add a "prefix" to your log, this way you can test that the right message was logged.

Example:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('foo')

def fun():
   try:
      raise Exception("An exception")
   except Exception as e:
      logger.debug(f'[error-x]: {e}')
```

Your test:

```
with self.assertLogs('foo', level=logging.DEBUG) as cm:
    call_your_method()
self.assertEqual(cm.output, ["DEBUG:foo:[error-x]: An exception"])
```

If you have more log messages with your exception message you can do:

```
self.assertIn("DEBUG:foo:[error-x]: An exception", cm.output)
```

You can check the [full example here](https://repl.it/@rafa_acioly/GullibleFaithfulSearchengine)